# IIS 8.5 multiple DNS - same IP/port binding

Tags: iis, web, server, iis-8.5

I am relatively new to setting up IIS:

We have 2 DNS names test1.com and test2.com which are bound to the same IP address (192.XX.XX.XX)
What I am trying to do is launch the same application; however different modules for both the DNS names.

For example: test1.com -> needs to resolve to http://servername/lite
and test2.com -> needs to resolve to http://servername/core

Essentially it is the same application; however the 1st one is a lite version and the 2nd one is the core application.

How can I set this up in IIS 8.5. The server configuration is Windows 2012 server.

Both are using the http protocol on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create two sites test1.com and test2.com which will refer to 
buindings http://test1.com/ and http://test2.com/ and refer to different physical paths, for example:
C:\inetpub\test1.com and C:\inetpub\test2.com

And you need to check DNS entries, they should refer to your IIS server.
This configuration should work totally fine without redirections to servername/lite or servername/core.